# how to turn my discord bot into a multiple servers bot

Tags: python, dictionary, discord.py, bots

I made a discord bot that thinks about a random number between X and Y and I used a game flag (ingame) to see if a game has already started or not but I have an error now that if server X started a game server Y can't start a game because server X started. Tried to use dictionaries to check each server individually but it doesn't really work. Even tried to add the guild name when someone invites the bot to the server but it didn't work aswell

```
games_in_progress = {}
@client.event
async def on_guild_join():
    server = guild.name
    print(server)
    games_in_progress[guild.name] = False
    print("Server added to the list")
global ingame
ingame = bool(True)

@client.command()
   guild = ctx.guild
   if guild not in games_in_progress:
       games_in_progress[guild] = True
   else:
       if guild == "True":
           await ctx.send("There is already a game in your server {}")
    if ingame == True:
       * do the code*
    else:
       await ctx.send("a game is already in progress, finish the game in {} to start a new 
       one!".format(gamechannel.mention))
```

Comment: First you need to get rid of the `global ingame` variable, since each server needs to track whether it's in game or not; therefore you cannot use a single global to do so.  Also, what is `if guild == "True"` supposed to do?  The server is almost certainly not named "True"

Comment: if guild == "True" suppose to go to the key "guild" in the dictionary and check if the value of this key is True (which means this guild has started a game).
the global ingame variable is a good point didn't think about that

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] and why using a dictionary didn't work.

Comment: You add its name (a string) to `games_in_progress` but then check if the actual object is in there or not. Also as mentioned earlier there's no point in checking if the guild is equal to the string "True". Did you mean `guild.name`? Also you can simply this and follow convention with `if ingame:` instead of `if ingame == True:`